# Remote debug of forked C++ application using gdbserver and vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, child-process, gdbserver

I can:

- Start the debugger and it attaches to my remote application
- Hit breakpoints in the main process
- Visually step through the code using vscode

I can't (help required):

- Hit breakpoints in child process after a fork()

I added some setup (setupCommands) for gdb in my vscode launch.json that should allow child process debugging

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Debug - MyHost",
            "gdbpath": "/usr/local/bin/gdb",
            "target": "MyHost:1234",
            "remote": true,
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "setupCommands": [
                {   "description":"In this mode GDB will be attached to both processes after a call to fork() or vfork().",
                    "text": "-gdb-set detach-on-fork off",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {   "description": "The new process is debugged after a fork. The parent process runs unimpeded.",
                    "text": "-gdb-set follow-fork-mode child",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "valuesFormatting": "parseText",
        }
    ],
}
```

The breakpoints in the child process, after a fork(), were not hit as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that you are forking only once? Try removing `detach-on-fork` and try typing in `info inferiors` in the debug console after forking

Comment: @mmomtchev  I step over `fork()`, the return value from `fork()` is 0, `info inferiors` shows one process: `* 1    process 39192`.  Ta!

Answer (score 0):

Fork spawns a new process. You are debugging the original process, not the fork.
To debug the fork, you will have to attach to the pid of the new instance.

Comment: The configuration file (launch.json) I have shown for vscode is meant to allow you to debug into "inferiors".